# How to open long path files in VBA?

Tags: excel

I'm getting an error message (Run-Time error 1004: Method Open of object Workbooks failed) in VBA when trying to open files with long path names

```
FileToOpen = "\\serverName\[long path > 260 characters long]\ExcelFile.xls
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen
```

I tried adding \?\UNC\ but I have the same error message

```
FileToOpen = "\\?\UNC\serverName\[long path > 260 characters long]\ExcelFile.xls
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen
```

Is there a way around to open long paths in VBA?

Comment: See [this post of May 20](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10733559-increase-the-218-character-filename-length-limit-t) from someone on the Microsoft Excel team. Seems like you may be running into an OS limit.  But there is a registry hack to get around that for Windows.  Maybe try it and see if it works for VBA (or power query or other methods of opening files from Excel).

Comment: I think that hack is only for Windows 10; not earlier versions.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541415/9808063) .. may be helpful .... or if ... you can create a hidden shortcut on a shorter path and open it in VBA