# VBA Excel copy folder/create folder

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I wanna use vba macro to copy or create folder, then I used the FileSystem function. I could run this program for the entire morning, but then suddenly got error saying path not found. I have checked all my path is correct. How should I fix it?

```
Sub CreateMissingFolders(DestinationFolder As String, FolderNames As Variant)
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim FolderName As Variant
    
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    For Each FolderName In FolderNames
        If Not FolderExists(DestinationFolder & "\" & FolderName) Then
            FileSystem.CreateFolder DestinationFolder & "\" & FolderName
        End If
    Next FolderName
End Sub
```

Comment: Pls try `If Not FileSystem.FolderExists(DestinationFolder & "\" & FolderName) Then`. What's the error number and text? Which line raise the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432250/access-files-with-long-paths-over-260

Answer (score 0):

**A Simple Test**

```vb
Sub Test()

    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Dim SubfolderNames() As Variant: SubfolderNames = Array( _
        2, "Name", "Today", "", Empty, CVErr(2007), "Another", "?")
    
    CreateMissingFolders FolderPath, SubfolderNames
    
End Sub
```

**The Method Expanded**

```vb
Sub CreateMissingFolders( _
        ByVal FolderPath As String, _
        ByVal SubfolderNames As Variant)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create Missing Folders"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = FolderPath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "Destination folder not found at """ & dFolderPath & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim SubfolderName As Variant, SubfolderPath As String
    Dim ErrNumber As Long, ErrDescription As String
    
    For Each SubfolderName In SubfolderNames
        If Not IsError(SubfolderName) Then
            If Len(SubfolderName) > 0 Then
                SubfolderPath = dFolderPath & SubfolderName
                If Not fso.FolderExists(SubfolderPath) Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                        fso.CreateFolder SubfolderPath
                        ErrNumber = Err.Number
                        ErrDescription = Err.Description
                    On Error GoTo ClearError
                    If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Run-time error '" & ErrNumber & "':" _
                            & vbLf & vbLf & ErrDescription & vbLf & vbLf _
                            & "Could not create folder """ & SubfolderPath _
                            & """!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "Created " & SubfolderPath
                    End If
                'Else ' already exists; do nothing
                End If
            Else ' is blank
                MsgBox "A blank was found in the Subfolder Names array.", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
        Else ' is an error
            MsgBox "An error was found in the Subfolder Names array.", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    Next SubfolderName

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```